How would you respond to this claim on Isaiah 53?
I was debating a Christian friend of mine, who has become somewhat persistent since I converted to the Jewish faith, but one of the critisms that he brought up, was that Isaiah 53 can't be about Israel, since in Isaiah 53:8, the servant is "cut off for the transgressions of my people" thus indicating that the servant cannot be Israel itself, since they are cut off because of Israel, how would you respond to this claim? I obviously reject it entirely, but I wanted to know how I could answer it.

Questions that are about "well the Christians say X, so how do we respond?" have repeatedly come up here and been shut down.

See this outstanding piece on Isaiah 53: https://download.yutorah.org/2024/1053/1087379/our-responsibility-to-humanity.pdf

Speaking as a Christian, I’d be curious about the variety of interpretations pre-Christianity. And although it’s often stated that a person is only punished for their own sins - yet there is a basis for the forgiveness of sins through the death of another in the Law. Namely: the death of the High Priest would pay the debt for all of the unintentional manslaughterers and cleanse the land that had been defiled of the spilt blood so that they could return home from exile

@RyanPierceWilliams the precedent does not extend, does it?

@YDJ In Christianity it would since Christ is the High Priest

@YDJ only an Aaronic Priest cannot be the King. There is precedent for non-Aaronic Priest-Kings, like Moses and Melchizedek. Christ is said to be of the order of Melchizedek

R' Tovia Singer will be your best friend here.

Is your friend named Connor Jones?

@RyanPierceWilliams the whole "order of melchizedek" is a scape goat. There is no order of melchizedek, the order is simply the order of Torah. Since Torah is given, the order is TORAH. Not some fictitious order that the book of hebrews made up. And no, don't quote Psalms 110.

@JewishContext That there have been Priest Kings like Moses and Melchizedek is well established in the scriptures. There is also nothing in scripture that asserts that there can only be Aaronic Priests going forward. Rather, the Messiah was to be one like Moses - and thus he would need to be both Priest and King. Thus the Messiah would need to be of a priesthood other than that of Aaron. And yes, Psalms 110.

@RyanPierceWilliams Then it is clear that Moses was temporarily a priest, and although Jewish tradition asserts Moses as a form of king, that was also short lived. And yes, the Torah does state that the line of Levi through Aaron are to be priests, and the line of Judah are to be kings. I find it bothersome that christians like you give 1 million titles to jesus just because. like lamb, king, lion, dove, etc. Is this jesus figure to be seen as some sort of zoo? When you stray from the laws of Torah this is what you are left with, various interpretations, various sects and denominations...

@JewishContext no it isn’t clear at all that Moses only temporarily served as Priest. There is no revocation of that role from him. Moses interceded for Aaron and not the other way around; by all rights he should have died when he constructed the Golden Calf. Moses is the one who constantly interceded for the people when they sinned - and Moses instructed Aaron on what to do. Moses is the one who went into the Tent of Meeting before the Lord and came out with his face shining so that he had to wear a veil. Furthermore, Gos made Moses Elohim while Aaron was made his prophet. Moses > Aaron

There is no straying from the Torah in the NT- rather you demonstrate a lack of knowledge of the Torah. Saying he only ruled “a short time” demonstrates this as well - he ruled over them for some 40 years, all through the wilderness and right up to the promised land

@RyanPierceWilliams Thats the problem with your line of thinking, "there is no revocation of that role from him (Moses)." So only if a verse EXPLICITLY says "and Moses no longer ever served as high priest" will you then accept such a fact? Nonsense, it is clear that Moses served as high priest for 8 days in Leviticus and then Aaron taking on that charge from Moses. This is seen in Parsha Tzav and Shemini. If we take your comment at face value then Moses was NOT a priest from the order of Melchizedek. Quite literally nonsense.. Anything to hold onto idolatry though right?

@RyanPierceWilliams And might I add, many christians believe melchizedek to have been jesus himself, so does that now make jesus a priest after his own order? I mean really, again, various interpretations lead to various denominations and sects all claiming theirs is correct. Although I am not saying you believe jesus was melchizedek, it is a widely accepted belief in some christian denominations such as the one I used to be a part of

@JewishContext There needs to be good reason for me to believe something, yes. Explicit scriptural statements are the most direct evidence - but I am not against less direct arguments that are well reasoned. Unfortunately I have yet to be presented with good reason to think that Moses was only temporarily a priest - and it doesn't match up with the biblical evidence. Whether Moses was or was not from the order of Melchizedek, while probable, is irrelevant. Even if we accept the tradition that he was only a King Priest for 8 days, he was still a King Priest - and not of the order of Aaron.

@JewishContext And I'm not sure what idolatry you are speaking of? Is it idolatry to recognize a prophet? Is it idolatry to recognize someone as a Son of God? I think not. Also, for clarity, I'm not a Trinitarian. I follow the scriptures and readily reject bad tradition - whether of Jewish or Christian origin. Rather, I follow the Jewish and Early Christian interpretation that the Son is the Wisdom of God (Proverbs 8), and the light of creation. See for instance my answer here: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/103695/43260

@JewishContext I do not understand the point of the argument either way. With Shem-Melchitzedek we know the chain of tradition from the Torah. We can also accept that this chain lasted through Ever. There does not seem any chain of such tradition afterwards. Only the line Avraham -Yitzchak- Yaakov remained. If there is no living chain of tradition for close to 2000 years, prophecy of an individual or to a selected group of sectarians cannot reinstate it or modify it. By contrast, Moshe who possesed the tradition was delegated to receive the Torah by all Jewish people who carried the tradition.

@YDJ The point is that there are priests outside of the order of Aaron. Such priests existed before Aaron, and they were greater than Aaron. Abraham paid tithe to Melchizedek. Moses ordained Aaron. Moses was made Elohim, and Aaron his prophet. So then, there is no conflict with Christ being a priest outside of the order of Aaron. In fact, to fulfill prophecy and for the Messiah to be like Moses, he had to be a Priest-King like Moses was - which means the Messiah could NOT be a descendant of Aaron.

@RyanPierceWilliams you avoid addressing the point about the chain of tradition from Adam haRishon. That is the important part of our tradition. Sons of Aharon Nadav and Avihu died because they tried teaching novelty unconnected with tradition ahead of Moshe and Aharon. It is an important matter and unless you address this point we cannot be seriously discussing the subject.

@YDJ Aaron’s sons died for offering strange fire contrary to the Lord’s commands - not for false teachings. Christ himself was a Rabbi that taught the Torah. Are there particular teachings you have in mind that are problematic?

@RyanPierceWilliams Where did the sons of Aharon learn this idea, G-d, Moshe, Aharon? That is a break in the tradition. As far as Jesus was a rabbi - that's not a proof for the independent "order of Melchtzedek" tradition, that Jesus supposedly switched to.

@YDJ Jesus established a New Covenant and with it a new priesthood. The New Covenant was prophesied by Jeremiah and is not a new idea. A different priesthood is necessitated by the New and better covenant. After all, righteousness is not passed down via physical descent. That is the problem with the Old Covenant: it is made with the flesh, with physical descendants.

@RyanPierceWilliams then it is not the order of Melchitzedek.

@YDJ Just because the Aaronic Priesthood is based upon physical lineage does not mean that any and all priesthoods must be based upon physical lineage. Rather, as seen in scripture with Eli and his sons - making someone a priest based purely upon physical descent is problematic

I too, coming from a christian background that since then I have renounced, used to claim such statements.
"How could Israel possibly bring back Israel if... well... Israel itself is in exile and sinning?" Primarily used to ask this on Isaiah 49:5-6
But truthfully it is not difficult at all. The answer is indeed that Israel brings back Israel to itself, and here is the thought process:

Israel shall never be totally demolished/disbanded
Jeremiah 31:35-37, Isaiah 44:21, 1 Kings 6:11-13


The wicked of Israel (and some righteous), are exiled due to collective sin
Ezekiel 39:23, 2 Kings 17:7-8, Deuteronomy 28:49-68


The remainder of Israel are brought back and return to righteousness & realize their survival depends on Torah observance alone
Ezekiel 36:24-38, Deuteronomy 30:1-10, 1 Kings 8:46-51



It can be seen that this return to Torah is what leads to the ultimate salvation and restoration of Israel. Now who else would advocate Torah observance? Clearly those who have seen the other side and lived, those who have the knowledge of God and His Torah.
So yes, the wise and righteous of Israel exhort the remainder to return to Torah. After all, the prophets are righteous Jews who exclaimed to KEEP TORAH... or else.
Combine this with the popular dictum: All Israel is responsible for each other (Shevuot 39a)
I hate to add this, but in truth, christians believe jesus himself was a Jewish man. So even if a christian wants to refute this method of thinking, according to their book, a Jew brings salvation to Jews FIRST (Matthew 15:24, Romans 1:16), meaning a Jew from Israel restores... Israel. You see?
